# Render cluster items on clicking cluster

Tags: android, google-maps

I have used
 https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/marker-clustering?hl=FR

to implement clustering in my google map.  When i zoom in - zoom out map, cluster items get rendered and clusters created.Everything works perfect. My question is that i want to rendered cluster item when user click on cluster,too.I didn't found any method for forcefully render cluster items. How should i do it?

I get the cluster click event on,

```
@Override
public boolean onClusterClick(Cluster<MapStoreData> cluster) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.v("cluster clicked", "found...");

    return true;
}
```

this method.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Finally i finished with incrementing zooming level of my map by any fixed value when cluster is clicked if map is not zoomed to its maximum level as a temporary solution. Better solutions are still accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i finished with incrementing zooming level of my map by any fixed value when cluster is clicked if map is not zoomed to its maximum level as a temporary solution. Better solutions are still accepted

Answer (score 0):

Use this in the click listener method:

```
// Cluster only
Collection<Marker> clusters = mClusterManager.getClusterMarkerCollection().getMarkers();
for(Marker marker : clusters) {
    onBeforeClusterRendered(getCluster(marker), new MarkerOptions());
}

// Cluster item only
Collection<Marker> markers = mClusterManager.getMarkerCollection().getMarkers();
for(Marker marker : markers) {
    onBeforeClusterItemRendered(getClusterItem(marker), new MarkerOptions());
}
```